# Is there more than one outcome for Halidrell Setsyn's storyline?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

In the Sith Warrior storyline, you meet Halidrell Setsyn on Nar Shadda:

[image: Halidrell]

Later on in the story...

> She is attacked by Lord Rathari and you are too late to save her.

Is this the only possible outcome?

Comment: I haven't played this storyline but I would say it's highly probable that you can't do anything.  The things you can change are usually minor and directly due to your choices, not someone else's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is the only outcome.